# custom sys.excepthook does not affect Sublime Text plugin API methods, is there any way around that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

The problem with Sublime Text is that when exception occurs in plugin interpreter the error message shows only in console pane, and that is easy to miss without opening it. There is no sound or any other visible indication that is able to catch my attention.

So the solution I thought would be create own exception handling function that can display a message error box aside of printing exception to the console.

```
import sys, sublime, sublime_plugin

def handle_sublime_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
  sublime.error_message("exception occured")

sys.excepthook = handle_sublime_exceptions

def my_test_exception_function():
  raise Exception("my_test_exception_function")

# uncommenting this line shows correct error box
# my_test_exception_function()

class EventDump(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_post_save(self, view):
    # here the function raises exception but excepthook
    # is reset to python's default
    # and only console is reacting
    my_test_exception_function()
```

And it works quite well, even syntax errors are visible when they occur after `sys.excepthook` redeclaration.

But when exception is raised in sublime's api classes like `EventDump` then this replacement does not work.

Is there any way to set custom exception hook for Sublime plugins so it will work with all the plugin code ?

Is it a python or sublime 'bug' ?